# Ads in dayDream Android

Tags: android, admob, daydream

In my dayDream application I have put an AdMob banner ad the bottom.
The problem is that when the screen is locked, and dreaming started, if the user clicks on the ads the browser opens properly but with blank url. When I open the pattern lock and see the browser url is blank.

Please help..

Comment: why are you using admob with daydream applications? there is no VR browser where you can navigate to in VR. Are you making the user take the headset off on clicking ads?